# Many lines with indentation in sed's substitute

Tags: bash, shell

How can I persist indentation in the multiline string used in `sed`?

What I'm doing is:

```
FILES_MATCH='<FilesMatch \\.php\$>\nSetHandler "proxy:unix:\/var\/run\/php\/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi:\/\/localhost"\n<\/FilesMatch>'
sed -i '' "s/ProxyPassMatch .*/${FILES_MATCH}/" "$HOME/Projects/${DIR_NAME}/deploy/apache/default.conf"
```

As a result I'm getting:

```
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Of course it should look like this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I control indentation in multiline substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I control indentation in multiline substitution?

You are literally substituting the text.

```
FILES_MATCH='<...>\n     SetHandler....'
#                    ^^^^^ - spaces
sed -i '' "s/ *ProxyPassMatch .*/${FILES_MATCH}/" 
#            ^^ - remove leading spaces
```

---

Ugh this is so hard with all the `\n` and `\/\/\/\/\/`. Consider using `awk` or `python` or `perl`. For starters use a different separator.

```
files_match='no need to escape //// characters now'
sed "s! *ProxyPassMatch .*!${FILES_MATCH}!"
#     ^                   ^              ^ - you can use any character
```

`$` is literally `$`, no need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the leading indentation in a group and apply it to the beginning of each line as you substitute, e.g.:

```sh
FILES_MATCH='\1<FilesMatch \\.php\$>\n\1    SetHandler "proxy:unix:\/var\/run\/php\/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi:\/\/localhost"\n\1<\/FilesMatch>'
sed "s/^\\([ \t]*\\)ProxyPassMatch .*/${FILES_MATCH}/"
```

The group `\([ \t]*\)` captures any leading spaces and tabs before `ProxyPassMatch` and each `\1` is substituted by the same. You need to add the additional indentation before `SetHandler` yourself.